# Definition of graph [Diestel's book]

Tags: graph-theory

> A graph is a pair $G=(V,E)$ of sets such that $E\subseteq [V]^2$;
> thus, the elements of $E$ are $2$-element subsets of $V$. To avoid
> notational ambiguities, we shall always assume tacitly that $V\cap
>  E=\varnothing$.

This is a definition of a graph from Diestel's book (fifth edition). By $[V]^2$ the author denotes the set of all $2$-element subsets of $V$. But we see that $V\cap E=\varnothing$ always because $V$ and $E$ are sets of distinct nature so they cannot have elements in common. Probably this a bad wording.

Can anyone explain it what the author meant? Or maybe I am wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess it could be possible to have vertex set $\{a,b,\{a,b\} \}$, but we are not allowing for such shenanigans to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for reply! But I still did no get the point. Why we cannot say that $E$ is the of pairs from $V$ where first and second coordinates are distinct. I have never learn graoh theory before so aplogies if I am asking dumb questions.

Comment: If the vertex set was $\{a,b,\{a,b\}\}$ then the edge connecting $a$ and $b$ would also be $\{a,b\}$ so we would have an edge that is also a vertex.

Comment: Ooh I see what you meant. Anyway but is wrong to have an edge which is also a vertex?

Comment: @ZFR: yeah, because the author says so. That's the line you quoted!

Comment: I don't know if it's wrong, but I think it makes things confusing in an unintended way.

Comment: @Onir, yeah maybe. I'll keep reading and probably at some time it becomes clear why the author assumed that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you take a look at this please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4140125/preimage-of-a-vertice-is-an-independent-set-of-vertices-in-a-graph

Comment: I already answered it before you even posted this comment...