# Preimage of a vertex is an independent set of vertices in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

This is an excerpt from Diestel's book and I'd like to clarify the following moment.

Suppose that $\varphi:V\to V'$ is a graph homomorphism and $x'\in \operatorname{Im}\varphi$ then $\varphi^{-1}(x')\neq \varnothing$. I'd like to show that $\varphi^{-1}(x')\subseteq V$ is independent set of vertices. If $v_1,v_2\in \varphi^{-1}(x')$ then $\varphi(v_1)=\varphi(v_2)=x'$. If  $v_1,v_2$ are adjacent then $\{\varphi(v_1),\varphi(v_2)\}=\{x'\}\in E'.$

But I do not see the contradiction. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{ \varphi(v_1),\varphi(v_2)\}$ cannot be an edge of $G'$ because it is a set that has only one element.

Comment: Why it cannot be an edge even it has only one element? I do not remember this in the definition of the graph.

Comment: The edges were subsets of $V$ that consisted of two elements.

Comment: Yes, $E\subseteq [V]^2$ which means that the elements of $E$ are pairs from $V$ but he did not mention that they should be distinct. Am I missing smth?

Comment: No no, $[V]^2$ is the set of subsets of $V$ of cardinality $2$, it is not the same as the usual set theory definition of $V^2$. He defines what $[V]^k$ is in the first page.

Comment: Ohhh I see. I read this but probably did not paid too much attention. And also I was confused why he did denote it by usual $V^2$. So $[V]^2$ means the set of all $2$-element subsets of $V$. Obvious if $v\in V$ then $\{v,v\}\notin [V]^2$ because it has one element. Right?

Comment: Yes indeed. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes sense :) You helped me twice today)

Comment: My pleasure. ${}{}$

Comment: Sorry but why did you erase your answer in my last topic?

Comment: You asked me to modify it but I don't really see the point of writing everything out, most of it seems pretty tedious.

Comment: In graph theory if you do everything from the base definitions things get very long.

Comment: I guess you are right. I just wanted to persuade myself somehow that this is correct reasoning but not just words.

Comment: I see, I'm not really sure how to do that, I hope someone answers it in a rigorous way.

Comment: Anyway thanks a lot for your constant help!

Comment: My pleasure.${}{}$